# Trouble Using values.yaml File with helm_release Resource in Terraform for Argo CD Application

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm, argocd

I'm currently working on deploying an Argo CD application using Terraform and the `helm_release` resource. While trying to leverage a `values.yaml` file for customization, I'm encountering issues where the Argo CD application isn't being created as expected. My objective is to replicate a YAML configuration that I successfully deployed using `kubectl apply -f kub.yaml`, but now I'm looking to achieve the same outcome within Terraform's Helm provider.

Below is my `kub.yaml` file that works well with direct `kubectl` application:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: intern
  namespace: argocd
  finalizers:
    - resources-finalizer.argocd.argoproj.io
spec:
  destination:
    namespace: default
    server: 'https://kubernetes.default.svc'
  source:
    path: Chart-test/
    repoURL: 'https://github.com/********'
    targetRevision: HEAD
    helm:
      valueFiles:
        - values.yaml
  project: default
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: true
      selfHeal: true
      allowEmpty: false
    syncOptions:
      - Validate=true
      - CreateNamespace=true
      - PrunePropagationPolicy=foreground
      - PruneLast=true
```

And here's the corresponding `values.yaml` file:

```
# values.yaml

applications:
  - name: intern
    namespace: argocd
    project: default
    source:
      repoURL: 'https://github.com/****'
      targetRevision: HEAD
      path: Chart-test/
    destination:
      namespace: default
      server: 'https://kubernetes.default.svc'
    syncPolicy:
      automated:
        prune: true
        selfHeal: true
        allowEmpty: false
    syncOptions:
      - Validate=true
      - CreateNamespace=true
      - PrunePropagationPolicy=foreground
      - PruneLast=true
    helm:
      valueFiles:
        - values.yaml
```

Below is my terraform code

```
    resource "helm_release" "argocd" {
  name             = "argocd"
  namespace        = "argocd"
  create_namespace = true
  version          = "3.35.4"
  repository       = "https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm"
  chart            = "argo-cd"
  values           = [file("values.yaml")]
}
```

However, despite closely mimicking the direct `kubectl` setup, the Argo CD application isn't being deployed as expected when using the `helm_release` resource in Terraform.

Could anyone kindly review my setup and provide insights into what might be causing the issue? Are there any specific intricacies or best practices I need to be aware of when working with the `values.yaml` file in the context of the `helm_release` resource within Terraform?

Any assistance or guidance would be highly appreciated

Comment: Please add the relevant terraform code to the question.

Comment: Do you need the reference to the `values.yaml` inside of the `values.yaml`?

Comment: The situation is as follows: I need to install an application immediately after setting up ArgoCD, using a link to a Helm chart in a Git repository. I have a `kub.yaml` file that works manually. Now, I need to rewrite this so that I can pass it as `values` during the ArgoCD installation.